# Why isn't tomcat serving the correct SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, tomcat6

I configured tomcat with SSL successfully and was using a self-signed certificate. Recently an issue arose where just having the client "Accept/trust" our certificate wasn't easy. We ended up purchasing a verisigin certificate for that server.

I've added the new certificate to the certificate to the key store. I've updated tomcat's *server.xml* file to use the alias, for the new certificate.  I've restarted both Tomcat and the Server.  Everytime I connect to the server I get the old Certificate.

**Enviornment:**

- Windows 2008 R2 - 64bit
- Tomcat 6.0.29 - installed as a service
- Java 1.6.0_23

*Connector* from **server.xml:**

```xml
<Connector port="443" maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="keystore.keys" keyalias="webapps2013"
           keystorePass="Redacted"             
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
```

I've even tried changing the key store, by moving the old certificate to a different alias and adding my new certicate at what the old alias name was.

I've tried it from multiple browsers, and workstations. (Cleared my cache too.)

So what do I need to do to get tomcat to pickup and serve my new certificate?

**UPDATE:**
  After a suggestion in one of the comments to clear tomcats cache.
  I stopped tomcat, deleted ${CATALINA_HOME}/work and restarted tomcat.
  It's still serving the old certificate.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've looked through *jakarta_service_date.log* *catalina.date.log* *manager.date.log* *stdout.date.log* and *stderr.date.log* I don't see any certificate errors. Although I am Seeing an odd error about Session Serialization.

```
Dec 11, 2013 10:46:27 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Tomcat6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\RCSLIBRRunner\SESSIONS.ser (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tomcat6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\RCSLIBRRunner\SESSIONS.ser (Access is denied)
```

followed by a stacktrace.  Other Applications threw tha similar same exception. It hasn't happened in a couple hours, I think it was a side effect from clearing tomcats cache.

Here's another Serialization error:

```
Dec 11, 2013 10:46:27 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stop
SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tomcat6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\RCSLIBRRunner\SESSIONS.ser (Access is denied)
```

Comment: Did you try to clear the Tomcat cache files ?

Comment: Which files are those?

Comment: Stop Tomcat service, then delete the folder named "Catalina" in your "work" folder, and restart Tomcat service

Answer (score 2):

We had trouble with the `protocol="HTTP/1.1"`, with errors in our logs. Our errors were

> Certificate file specified or invalid file format

Based on some "[google research](http://rajblogsworld.blogspot.com/2011/05/setting-property-keystorefile-did-not.html)", we used this for `protocol` instead:

`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`

Our `Connector` is as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore"
    keystorePass="******"
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out I had a typo in my `Connector`

It should be:

```xml
<Connector port="443" maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="keystore.keys" keyAlias="webapps2013"
           keystorePass="Redacted"             
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
```

**Note:** the first a in `keyAlias` is capitalized.

Turns out that if the alias isn't listed it just silently serves the first key it finds in the key store.